# select and contain do not work in cakephp query

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

When I query without `select()` I get `contain()` [owner] array, but using select() with params it doesn't contain `[owner]` array. Is there any problem using select and contain at same time ?

```
$payments = $this->Payments->find()
                        ->select($this->Payments)
                        ->select(['tot_amount'=>'sum(Payments.amount)'])
                        ->select(['tot_owner_amt'=>'sum(Payments.owner_amt)'])
                        ->select(['tot_admin_amt'=>'sum(Payments.admin_amt)'])
                        ->contain(['Owners'])
                        ->group(['Payments.owner_id'])
                        ->all();
        debug($payments); die();
```

### Debug array

```
 \src\Controller\PaymentsController.php (line 72)

object(Cake\ORM\ResultSet) {

    'items' => [
        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Payment) {

            'id' => (int) 4,
            'user_id' => (int) 4,
            'owner_id' => (int) 5,
            'wifi_id' => (int) 2,
            'payment_unique_key' => 'pay-9999',
            'payment_type' => 'paypal',
            'amount' => (float) 10,
            'owner_amt' => (float) 1,
            'admin_amt' => (float) 9,
            'ispaid' => false,
            'paid_at' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

                'time' => '2017-01-10T11:21:00+00:00',
                'timezone' => 'UTC',
                'fixedNowTime' => false

            },
            'is_refund' => false,
            'isactive' => true,
            'isdel' => null,
            'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

                'time' => '2017-01-10T11:22:24+00:00',
                'timezone' => 'UTC',
                'fixedNowTime' => false

            },
            'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

                'time' => '2017-01-10T11:30:26+00:00',
                'timezone' => 'UTC',
                'fixedNowTime' => false

            },
            'tot_amount' => '10.00',
            'tot_owner_amt' => '1.00',
            'tot_admin_amt' => '9.00',
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Payments'

        },
        (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\Payment) {

            'id' => (int) 1,
            'user_id' => (int) 1,
            'owner_id' => (int) 6,
            'wifi_id' => (int) 1,
            'payment_unique_key' => 'adfasdf',
            'payment_type' => 'paypal',
            'amount' => (float) 500,
            'owner_amt' => (float) 50,
            'admin_amt' => (float) 449,
            'ispaid' => false,
            'paid_at' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

                'time' => '2017-01-10T11:21:00+00:00',
                'timezone' => 'UTC',
                'fixedNowTime' => false

            },
            'is_refund' => false,
            'isactive' => true,
            'isdel' => null,
            'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

                'time' => '2017-01-10T11:22:24+00:00',
                'timezone' => 'UTC',
                'fixedNowTime' => false

            },
            'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

                'time' => '2017-01-10T11:30:26+00:00',
                'timezone' => 'UTC',
                'fixedNowTime' => false

            },
            'tot_amount' => '2000.00',
            'tot_owner_amt' => '200.00',
            'tot_admin_amt' => '1798.00',
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Payments'

        }
    ]

}
```

Did i miss anything in above code? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to select the owners array in `select` like `select($this->Payments->Owners)` ,  Thanks @burzum

### Solutions

```
$payments = $this->Payments->find()
                        ->select($this->Payments)
                        ->select(['tot_amount'=>'sum(Payments.amount)'])
                        ->select(['tot_owner_amt'=>'sum(Payments.owner_amt)'])
                        ->select(['tot_admin_amt'=>'sum(Payments.admin_amt)'])
                        ->select($this->Payments->Owners)
                        ->contain(['Owners'])
                        ->group(['Payments.owner_id'])
                        ->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't select the owner data it doesn't fetch the owner? Pretty simple as that. You select only the payments, add the owner like you do with the payments.